# How to enable Memory monitors in Eclipse (Java project)?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, memory

I am trying to inspect the memory contents (bytes) of an object in a Java project.
The program is paused in the Eclipse IDE.
How ever: the `Memory view` is disabled - as in: the `Add Memory monitor` `+` button is greyed out.

[image: Eclipse-Memory_view-disabled]

Why?

Answer (score 3):

This question seems to be unanswered for quite a while and the one above sure doesn't help. This is the only post about it I could find.

In the [Eclipse Help platform](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp) information about Memory view can be found in the [`C/C++ Development User Guide > Reference > Debug Views > Memory View`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_memoryview.htm) but that isn't useful when were on Java. In the `Java Development Guide` it isn't as easy to find. Adding just Java Development Guide to the scope and searching for memory returns information about the [Memory View](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-memory-inspect.htm?cp=1_3_6_8) in Running and Debugging but doesn't help very much. It is a view but isn't found in the same `> Reference > Debug Views >` as the C/C++ Guide.

When running a program in Debug mode in Eclipse C\C++ the `+` in the Memory view lights up and you can add addresses. However, running your program in Debug view doesn't seem to do the same in Eclipse Java. I'm assuming it can't be used in Java Eclipse or has a special case use that isn't mentioned.

Comment: In 2017 memory view not works for me with Java either

Answer (score -2):

Using JConsole
The JConsole graphical user interface is a monitoring tool that complies to the Java Management Extensions (JMX) specification. JConsole uses the extensive instrumentation of the Java Virtual Machine (Java VM) to provide information about the performance and resource consumption of applications running on the Java platform.

In the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE platform) 6, JConsole has been updated to present the look and feel of the Windows and GNOME desktops (other platforms will present the standard Java graphical look and feel). The screen captures presented in this document were taken from an instance of the interface running on Windows XP.

Starting JConsole
The jconsole executable can be found in JDK_HOME/bin, where JDK_HOME is the directory in which the Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed. If this directory is in your system path, you can start JConsole by simply typing jconsole in a command (shell) prompt. Otherwise, you have to type the full path to the executable file.

Command Syntax
You can use JConsole to monitor both local applications, namely those running on the same system as JConsole, as well as remote applications, namely those running on other systems.

source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html